# Add more pods, after you have implemented pods into your project

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have already added pods to my ios (Firebase and Firebase Database), however, I would like to also add the Firebase storage pod. I have looked online and seen that I have to use pod update, however, I can not seem to figure out how to make it work.

[image: Podfile]

I have tried adding the pod to my file (as can be seen above), but when I try to run `pod update podfile` It says that the pod has not been installed. Am I doing something very wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you show the error

Comment: Please always post code in textual form, instead of images.

Comment: post your error @joshLor

Comment: why not try pod install ?